# Word that describes people who are easily impressed?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Is there a specific word that describes people who are easily impressed?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Consider *[susceptible](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/susceptible)* ("likely to be affected by something", "easily influenced or tricked; credulous" and "(medicine) especially sensitive, especially to a stimulus"); and also consider *[impressionable](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/impressionable)* ("Susceptible of impression; capable of receiving impressions; emotional").  An "impressionable person" may be someone on whom it's easy to make an impression, or may be someone at a formative stage such that impressions will last.  Note, making an impression on someone can differ from [impressing](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/impress) them.

Comment: Of the two, impressionable stands out to me.

Comment: What @rsegal said. *Susceptible* is much more general - you can be susceptible to many different things. *Impressionable* is exactly what the OP asked for (IMHO).

Answer (score 14):

*Gullible, naive, guileless, ingenuous* and *unsuspecting* might get close, but I doubt if there's any single word that specifically captures the 'easily impressed' sense.

Comment: +1 Gullible carries a connotation of being easily duped, but describes the characteristic equally to impressionable.

Answer (score 9):

[Credulous](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/credulous) is not quite right (too easily believe things rather than are impressed by them) but may work depending on what the situation is you are trying to describe.

Answer (score 8):

I would add [indiscriminate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/indiscriminate) and [fawning](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fawning?show=0&t=1344345798), the second especially for those already familiar with the subject they are impressed by. The is also a sense in which [generous](https://www.google.com/search?q=generous) applies.

Answer (score 1):

Rube often carries this connotation, but it also has more of a condescending tone.

From Merriam Webster:
1:  an awkward unsophisticated person :  rustic
2:  a naive or inexperienced person